# How can I create a map of mongo::BSONObjBuilder using mongo C++ API?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I would like to do something like this

```
std::map<int, mongo::BSONObjBuilder> items;

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  items[i].append("description", "Car")
          .append("type", "vehicle")
          .append("color", "green");
}
```

I tried this but it generates compile time errors. Is this possible? If not what would be the best way to implement something like this?

Comment: "I tried this but it generates compile time errors." How are we supposed to help you if you don't tell use ***what exact errors you get***?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that std::map requires that values be copyable, but BSONObjBuilder is explicitly defined as non-copyable: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r2.0.4/bson/bsonobjbuilder.h#L86.

(Note that this was also posted to our mailinglist at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/ZVdJG64Uqic. There may be follow up discussion there.)